# Thermal Physics, Specific Question

Tags: homework-and-exercises, thermodynamics

Question: The melting point of copper is 1080 degrees Celsius and its heat of fusion is 200 kJ/kg.  If a copper coin at this temperature is completely melted by the absorption of 2000 J of heat, what is the mass of the coin in kg?

---

I am not sure which formula(s) to use. Is the melting point even needed in this particular problem with it's given information?

Thank you.

Comment: Imagine the coin is exactly one kilogram. How much energy would it take to melt the coin? How about half a kilo...?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The equation for latent heat (or using the heat of fusion) is:

> ```
> Q = L * m
> ```
>
> where:
>
> ```
> Q is heat energy
> L is latent heat (heat of fusion)
> m is the mass of the substance undergoing phase change
> ```

There are some hints in the units, too. kJ is kilojoules, and kg is mass. Using the above equation, I'm sure you can get it.